# How to add HtmlTable to HtmlTableRow?

Tags: c#, asp.net, nested, html-table

I have a `HtmlTable` (parent) and want to nest another `HtmlTable` into parent's `HtmlTableRow`.

I tried this code:

```
HtmlTable parent=new HtmlTable();
HtmlTableRow row = new HtmlTableRow();
HtmlTable child = new HtmlTable();
HtmlTableRow row2 = new HtmlTableRow();
row2.Cells.Add(CreateTableCell("cell1"));
row2.Cells.Add(CreateTableCell("cell2"));
child.Rows.Add(row2);
row.InnerHtml=child.InnerHtml;
parent.Rows.Add(row);
```

but it give me this error:

> `HtmlTable` does not support the `InnerHtml` property.

This error occurred because *This property is inherited from the `HtmlContainerControl` class and is not applicable to the `HtmlTable` class*

Is there any replacement for this method?

Comment: @SonerGönül I know that. VS don't show any syntax error but in runtime that error occurs.

Comment: @SonerGönül see caution part in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltable.innerhtml(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Add the table to a cell, add the cell to the row

Comment: It's not legal to put a table in a tr.  tr can contain td or th.  What does it even mean to put a table in a tr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only objects you can put into a TableRow are TableCells and TableHeaderCells.  Any other content (like another table) has to first go into one of these.  This is exactly like the html tr element, which can only contain td or th elements.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try by taking a div, once you created Htmltable, set Html Table as content of the div.

for example

```
 div.innerHtml = htmlTable;
```

hope that help

Comment: this is impossible because `HtmlTable` cannot converted to `String`.

Answer (score 0):

From *[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltable.innerhtml%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)*;

> Do not read from or assign a value to this property. Otherwise, a
>   System.NotSupportedException exception is thrown. This property is
>   inherited from the HtmlContainerControl class and is not applicable to
>   the HtmlTable class.

Try like this;

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
child.RenderControl(htw)
```

Comment: This not worked ;because you don't fill `row`! How can I fill `row` with `child`?